# c function convert "fffoootoo" to "foto" (leaves out following repeating characters)

Tags: c

The task would be to remove following characters that are repeating from a char array, like "deeeciddeee" -> "decide" or "phhhonne" -> "phone".

I have a function that crashes the console, and I can't spot the bug:

```
char* my_unique(char *first, char *last) {
    char* ret=first;
    for(int i=0; first+i!=last; i++){
        if(first[i]==first[i+1]){
            for(int j=i; first+j!=last; j++)
                first[j]=first[j+1];
            last--;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

it is called this way:

```
char* a="oooat";
a=my_unique(a, a+strlen(a));
cout<<a;
```

please help me!

Comment: Probably want to show us how you are calling it.

Comment: If you are using C++ it's a good idea to use a `std::string` instead of c-style strings. If it's C++ then tag only c++. Same for C. Please, don't use unrelated tags.

Comment: You can't write to a string literal. Try `char a[] = "oooat"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides a small bug (you should add the line `i--;` after `last--;`, because you're deleting the character at possition i, so what has been the character at `i+1` became the new character at possition i. If you don't decrease i, it will be increased and you jump over a character) the code runs perfectly fine IF it is called with

```
const char* b = "oooat";
char* a = new char[strlen(b) + 1];
for (size_t c = 0; c < strlen(a) + 1; c++) { a[c] = b[c]; }
a = my_unique(a, a + strlen(a));
cout << a;
delete[] a;
```

Notice that I've used a edit-able copy of the string, as the literal itself is of type `const char*` and therefor can't be changed at all. And as I said, this works perfectly fine and prints "oat", just as expected, without any crash. So your problem might be that you try to edit a const string literal? In that case you might consider to copy it, as I did, or use `std::string` (if you code in C++).

Comment: thanks! it doesn't change the sad fact though that our university check-system doesn't accept it...

Comment: @kabir If the university check-system expects C code, then lines like `cout << a` will be rejected, since they are C++, not C. This answer adds `new` and `delete`, which are also C++ only.

Answer (score 0):

There are many beginner mistakes in the code.
Let me point you one by one.

---

```
char* a="oooat";
a=my_unique(a, a+strlen(a));
cout<<a;
```

1. When you declare a string like this : `char* a="oooat"`, `a` is a string literal. The memory for the string is allocated into text section of the program. Which basically means you cannot modify the values inside the strings. You can only read from them. Hence when you are passing pointer `a` to the function and modifying it, it will result in segmentation fault(Illegal access to memory).
2. Why do you need a ret pointer here? `char* ret=first;`

   You are passing a pointer and modifying the value inside it. Hence the new data will be reflected in the calling function and we need not return it explicitly. So, it is redundant.
3. Overall logic can be simplified as well

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MYSTR "ooooat"

void my_unique(char *first, char *last) {
    int size = last - first;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    for (; i < size; i++, j++) {
        first[j] = first[i];
        // Continue to check how many repetitions are there
        while (i + 1 < size && (first[i] == first[i+1])) i++;
    }

    // In the end terminate the string with a NULL.
    first[j] = '\0';
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = MYSTR;
    my_unique(a, a+strlen(a));
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in C.  There are simpler ways of doing this in C++, and the code can definitely be condensed but has been left simpler for readability.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char* fix(char *input) {
    char *lookahead = input;
    char *newchar, *ret;
    // Determine Max Return String Length
    int len = 0;
    while (*lookahead != '\0') {
        len++;
        lookahead++;
    };
    // allocate max possible memory needed and set the pointers
    ret = malloc(len);
    newchar = ret;
    lookahead = input;
    *newchar = *lookahead; // copy the first character
    while (*lookahead != 0) {
        lookahead++; // incrementing this ptr first starts lookahead at 2nd character and
                     // ensures the null terminator gets copied before the while loop ends
        if (*newchar != *lookahead) { // only copy new characters to new return string
            newchar++;
            *newchar = *lookahead;
        };
    };
    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give my answer so that it makes the as little changes as possible to your original code, while using the simplest methods.

The main problem has already been identified by the previous comments - **you cannot alter a string literal.**

Also, the line of code

```
i--;
```

has to be placed as well, with the reason well clarified above.

While making an editable version of the string may be a good way of fixing the problem, a more straightforward way would be to make it a local string, as such :

```
char b[] = "oooat";
```

but doing this will make it incompatible with the return type of your my_unique function (char*). But why would you need a return type in the first place, if you are fixing the string itself?

My final code would look like this :

```
void my_unique(char *first, char *last) {

  char* ret=first;
  for(int i=0; first+i!=last; i++){
      if(first[i]==first[i+1]){
          for(int j=i; first+j!=last; j++)
              first[j]=first[j+1];
          last--;
          i--;
      }
  }
}
```

making the function return void.

Hope this helps.